# CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x2805609a0> , -[LocalNotification initWithCoder:]:

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm using Core Data in my project, and my "Task" entity has 2 "Transformable" properties with their custom classes ("Subtasks" and "LocalNotification")

My app crashes with the following error:

> [error] error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request:
>    , -[LocalNotification
>   initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2826afb00
>   with userInfo of (null)
>
> CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request:
>    , -[LocalNotification
>   initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2826afb00
>   with userInfo of (null)
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LocalNotification
>   initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2826afb00'

And the same is for "Subtasks" property.

Here is how they look like:

[image]

Here is my "`LocalNotification + CoreDataClass.swift`" file

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(LocalNotification)
public class LocalNotification: NSManagedObject {

}
```

And here is "`LocalNotification + CoreDataProperties.swift`" file

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension LocalNotification {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<LocalNotification> {
        return NSFetchRequest<LocalNotification>(entityName: "LocalNotification")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: Int64
    @NSManaged public var identifier: String?
    @NSManaged public var triggerDate: NSDate?

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try making the `notifications` a Relationship with a "Destination" of LocalNotification, with a "Type" of "To Many" (you access this in the Data Model Inspector when you select the `notifications` Relationship.

Comment: @Emma did you found any solution for this problem, or did the above comment solution worked?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?